# Two forms same page - one returns null the other works

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

When I run         `$value = $request->session()->all();` Controller one gives the value 'product' as null. The second gives the right product id. They are on the same page. Both are forms within bootstrap modals. Why are they giving different session data? Stumped.

**the form is submitted from a product page -> the id i want isnt submitted from the form -> the id is from the product page**

**Controller One**

```
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ControllerOne@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}


    {{Form::label('time', 'Select a Time')}}
    {{Form::time('time', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Time'])}}

    {{Form::label('date', 'Select a Date')}}
    {{Form::text('date', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date'])}}
    <div class="modal-footer">
    {{Form::submit('Add', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller Two**

```
  {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ControllerTwo@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

                        {{Form::label('listing', 'Price (NZD)')}}
                        {{Form::text('price', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Price'])}}

                        {{Form::label('listing', 'Name')}}
                        {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])}}

                        {{Form::label('listing', 'Phone Number')}}
                        {{Form::number('phone_number', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Phone Number'])}}

                        {{Form::label('listing', 'Comments/Conditions')}}
                        {{Form::textarea('conditions', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Comments/Conditions'])}}


                        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: why are you using `$request->session()->all();` instead of `$request->all()` to retrieve your form values?

Comment: @AmrAly the form is submitted from a product page -> the id i want isnt submitted from the form -> the id is from the product page

Comment: could you please add the store method code of your both controllers to the post

Comment: @AmrAly $value = $request->session()->all(); is what is being run in both the rest should not effect it

Comment: First of all your question and provided description is totally different. 
Second, both of your form does not send any `product` so in both controller you should not get any `product` unless its set from any where else.
Last, as you said you are getting `product` in `ControllerTwo`, you should see the code there, specially the route, extended controller, traits etc.